# Firebase Messaging not working without GoogleServices-Info.plist

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I was under the impression that `GoogleServices-Info.plist` is not mandatory anymore since FlutterFire CLI nicely puts config files on dart code, like `firebase_options_flavor1.dart`

App was working without GoogleServices-Info.plist but after adding Firebase Messaging, it started to crash without this file.

My questions are:

1. Is GoogleServices-Info.plist still required?
2. If yes, is it possible to add firebase config remotely? With dart, it's easy. But it's hard to inject in native code.

Some relevant messages on Github.
Comment that exactly describes my problem: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8119#issuecomment-1048738598

Issue where dart initialization crashes with notifications: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/7752

Comment where dart-only initialization not working: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8119#issuecomment-1047823455

Answer (score 2):

The issue with Firebase Messaging and the GoogleServices-Info.plist file is a known issue, and it has been reported on the FlutterFire GitHub repository or somewhere in internet.

GoogleServices-Info.plist is still required for Firebase to work properly in your app. This file contains important configuration information for your Firebase project, including your app's bundle ID and API key.

While it is possible to add Firebase configuration remotely using Dart code, this approach is not recommended for security reasons.

The recommended approach is to include the GoogleServices-Info.plist file in your project, and then let Firebase read the configuration information from this file.

The issue is caused by a conflict between the Firebase Messaging plugin and the GoogleServices-Info.plist file, and it can be resolved by either removing the GoogleServices-Info.plist file or updating the Firebase Messaging plugin to the latest version.

Regarding the comment you mentioned, it is true that Firebase initialization can sometimes fail when using Dart-only initialization, especially when it comes to Firebase Cloud Messaging. In this case, it is recommended to use native initialization instead, as it is more reliable and less error-prone.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. So you are saying removing the config file or updating the plugin will fix this conflict? Plugins and Flutter(stable) are already the latest at the moment. The problem is app crashes without config and it started to happen when I added firebase messaging. So it sounds like opposite

Comment: Based on the information you provided, it sounds like removing the config file caused your app to crash when you added Firebase Messaging, whereas the expected behavior is that your app should continue to work without the config file when using FlutterFire CLI's dart code-based configuration.

Comment: In this case, it's possible that the Firebase Messaging plugin is dependent on the GoogleServices-Info.plist file and requires it to function properly,even though other FlutterFire plugins may work without it.

Comment: If you want to continue using the Firebase Messaging plugin in your app, you will need to include the GoogleServices-Info.plist file in your project. Alternatively, you could consider using a different push notification service that does not require this configuration file.

Comment: As for the second issue you mentioned, where the Dart-only initialization is not working, it's possible that this is a separate issue that's not related to the Firebase Messaging plugin. It may be worth opening a new issue on the FlutterFire GitHub repository with more details about the problem you're experiencing.